# Zoom in on country with tmap in R

Tags: r, maps, data-visualization, gis, geospatial

I need to make a map of West Africa that shows points in Liberia, Sierra Leone, and Guinea. I am just learning about spatial mapping in R, and this is the code I'm starting with ([source](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/3.3-2/topics/tm_symbols)). I have two questions:

1. How can I zoom in so the map only displays West Africa?
2. How can I make an inset showing the location of West Africa relative to the whole continent?

```
library(tmap)
library(ggplot2)
data(World, metro)
metro$growth <- (metro$pop2020 - metro$pop2010) / (metro$pop2010 * 10) * 100
Africa <- World %>%
  subset(continent == 'Africa')

tm_shape(Africa) +
    tm_fill("grey70") +
tm_shape(metro) +
    tm_bubbles("pop2010", col = "growth", 
        border.col = "black", border.alpha = .5, 
        style="fixed", breaks=c(-Inf, seq(0, 6, by=2), Inf),
        palette="-RdYlBu", contrast=1, 
        title.size="Metro population", 
        title.col="Growth rate (%)") + 
tm_format("World")
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding your first question you may filter based on the iso codes or country names, e.g.: 
```Africa <- World %>% subset(continent == 'Africa') %>% filter(iso_a3 %in% c("BEN", "BFA", "CIV"))```

Comment: This book https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html should help you out :)